# Retrieving printf format parameter by type

Tags: c++, lambda, template-meta-programming, stdtuple

The following lambda is supposed to return the string formatter for printf and alike at compiletime, however it doesn't seem to work as intended and I can't get behind it.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgCcpAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcVyJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BAVU1AnUNBEUR0bEJtvWNzTltwz2hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1CYbbg3ETACeh9gmGgCCm9u7mAdHCgTEocAA%2BgBueJgA7pdrnczFsGDsvPtDm4nK9iJhWEDbsDQgQ9iwmKEIHMDgB2Ky3PZEvZeNJGPYAFWeABESQw0sAwug9sgEA1DgSbsSWQJXphVEliHtXugQCA4R8fn9/nsqCw0YdaSYAKxWMwANhV1OxewAtJdhQRReK3pLfgC8ZzudyRWKCF4kvRoayGqQ6QymSy2WRhQgSAQ3V56XhGZhmQo/Y03ajSMDrfH3SHPTG9rQBMBA8HQ8y00Y3bngKn05mPWGi%2BSCwb0D4WBcNlaE2h6QR%2BYLDca0gAvTCfNEYpKfLtPRXtu0O%2BiDvDdn7QrA7AhnJKYCDVli1uZA%2Btxxu8lsCoW28VTntovDoVQ0g6q8ya5XU6GHoe9gB0r72AEkFJcIIfQlhVIOmAAI5eIwqzQp%2Br7PpcG74tuCbEo%2Bx69ns8IKhstIaBy8EIXsEAqmqt73viqGYOhtKfhypH2sQDCjuKrA9kwX5HBSbpzrQC5Lj%2BRpisAZEQSx2ArjWZxzBuGxXPWeLajiJi4m48luHsUESQ2uHUcsdFodhhIJvJ2qHhiADWPZ/vygEgWBmDQv2k7dkCcG4tSak4dyaFafRJznA%2BvEmu8RhSgCbp2UOjkWAcZhmOYyoIAg6DmAEkXRWYsUIF4iVuolMXxZlyU5RlUVZVFMUJUV%2BWpYVSXZaltBldVJW1VVxUpcqtB1XlNVtd4iUyQRZ6qFqulcsSBnYsNNp%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%2B99H7Pw2K/XgYZP6lz0Pwb2ohxD%2B24YHFQ6hRah1IP8U4SR7aHw4HtUg6DC6cEJjNYhaJUBUHPlfG%2Bd8H5Pxfm/CAHgUaUO/lwX%2BOCQaAIQAiLAcQK7G3AXbSQypnxvRzvEHOriNDuKxvI36HAsFA1wc9V671jYbGPhgv65iAHSLMBEhR/jolPVIMXNIzhJBAA%3D%3D)

```
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using T = unsigned char;
    constexpr std::string_view fmt = [&]() -> std::string_view {
        std::tuple<char, unsigned char, short, unsigned short, int,
            unsigned int, long, unsigned long, long long, unsigned long long> dummy;
        constexpr std::size_t map_size = std::tuple_size_v<decltype(dummy)>;
        constexpr std::size_t idx = [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
            std::size_t ret = 0;
            ([&]{ ret = Is; return std::same_as<T, decltype(std::get<Is>(dummy))>; }() || ...);
            return ret;
        }(std::make_index_sequence<map_size>{});
        return std::array<std::string_view, map_size>{ "%hhd", "%hhu", "%hd", "%hu", "%d", "%u", "%ld", "%lu", "%lld", "%llu" }[idx];
    }();
    std::cout << fmt << std::endl;
}
```

Currently it outputs:

```
%llu
```

Expected result:

```
%hhu
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`decltype(std::get<Is>(dummy))` is `T&` for a mutable `std::tuple`, `const T&` for immutable `std::tuple`. Use `std::tuple_element_t` instead:

```cpp
            ([&]{ ret = Is; return std::same_as<T, std::tuple_element_t<Is, decltype(dummy)>>; }() || ...);
```

Comment: yep, that was it. I don't quite understand what the difference is though, since std::get returns a tuple_element as well :/ EDIT: Ahh I get it, it's about the reference. I would have to clear it from cvref first.

Comment: `using types = std::tuple<..>` might replace `dummy` too [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cv433cPzh).